# How to Join a Fact Table to Junk Dimension

Tags: sql, join, data-modeling, dimensional-modeling, fact

If I have a fact table and want to join it to a Junk Dimension table to hold the various combinations of attributes for a fact how do I join this in SQL in the underlying ETL efficiently after creating the Dim table?

Do I simply have to join the Fact Table source data to the Dim Junk on the various columns that exist in the Junk? What if there are 10+? Will this just be a case of 10+ joins?

EDIT: Added schema and explanation below

Example Schema below

Fact Action Table

- Date
- Action Key
- Dim Junk Key
- Case # (Degenerate Dimension)

Dim Junk Case

- Key
- Status
- Manager
- Source

When creating the SQL to generate the Fact Table from its source data I need to choose a key from the junk case dimension. Would this be done by joining the Fact Source data to the Junk table via the Case?

I imagine the SQL would be like:

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3, JC.[Junk Surrogate Key],     
FROM FactSource FS    
  LEFT JOIN CASESOURCEDATA CS ON FS.Case# = CS.Case#    
  LEFT JOIN DimJunkCase JC 
    ON 
      JC.column1 = CS.column1 AND    
      JC.column2 = CS.column2 AND    
      JC.column3 = CS.column3 AND    
      JC.column4 = CS.column4
```

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result. The question is not fully clear to me.

Comment: It's my understanding that a junk dimension table would have a `junk_id` to indicate which `junk` row belongs to each `fact` row. Like on your `fact` table you would have a column called `junk_id`. How else would you maintain the relationship between the fact table and the junk?

Comment: JNevill is correct. All Dims in a star schema should join to fact tables on a single integer PK column (insert int size), including the junk dimension. You do that mapping in your ETL.

Comment: @MitchWheat I understand this concept. My confusion comes when trying to generate the Surrogate Key in the Fact Table. Would the surrogate Key just be selected in the underlying SQL after joining Fact Source Data to the Junk Dimension? e.g.

SELECT DimJunk.[Junk Surrogate Key], column1, column2, column3 column4

FROM FactSource

LEFT JOIN DimJunk ON 
column1 = column1 AND
column2 = column2 AND
column3 = column3 AND
column4 = column4 AND

What if there are a large number of attributes? Would it just be a large number of Joins?

Comment: Yes I get that but to choose the correct primary key in the fact table, I would have to create a join of the columns from the fact data to the junk dimension wouldn't I? How else would I pick the correct Dim Key? @MitchWheat

Comment: @JNevill See comments above

Comment: @Chaddeus: yes, your ETL needs to match all the junk dimension attributes, to assign the junk_id. If you  have more than 10-15 attributes in a junk dimension, you might consider creating separate dimensions

Comment: @MitchWheat Thank you. So it would just be a case of multiple joins for the columns I have in the junk dimension?

Comment: This is a lot of words and a lot of comments and none of this is going to get us to an answer. Please share your table schema and sample data, and desired results after this join. What you've described doesn't sound much like a junk table and I fear there is some major issue here like a failure in your ETL steps to store the id of the relevant row of your junk table in your fact table for later joining. Please share schema, sample data, and desired results and this will all be clear without 1000 words.

Comment: @JNevill Added schema example and SQL

Comment: That's helpful. It sounds like the question you are asking is specifically about when you are loading the fact table, how do you determine which junk key you should include in the record? I, and I believe others, misunderstood thinking that the junk key was already stored in the fact table and you were just wanting to join the things.

Comment: @JNevill Yes that's right. I apologize for the misunderstanding and poor question format.

I am specifically asking about generating the correct junk key during the ETL process of loading the Fact Table

Comment: I believe your approach is good. The whole idea here is that you suffer through slow/painful ETL to load these tables so that users selecting on them get fast responses. So that awful `column1 = column1 AND column2=column2` is a necessary evil to determine the right junk record id to store on your fact table.

Comment: @JNevill Thank you very much for your answer. I had been doing it this way but had a feeling I maybe doing it a wrong and convoluted way. Now I know it was correct. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Answered in comments. Initial SQL was correct. Multiple Joins must be used to join fact to junk dimension

Comment: It would be great if the answer can be summarized and put as a proper answer instead of being deep inside comment section. Comment isn't exactly the first place someone with a similar question might look at.